# How Do You Select VALUES using Xpath's starts-with?

Tags: python, xpath

```html
<option value="Employee19343">Person1</option> <br />
<option value="Other19343">Person2</option> <br />
```

.
.

I want the value that starts with "Employee"!

This doesn't work - invalid syntax

```
value = tree.xpath('//option/@value[starts-with(.,'Employee')]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using below selector to get the exact option

```
//option[starts-with(@value, 'Employee')]
```

This will return expected options

So the code should look like

```
value = tree.xpath('//option[starts-with(@value, "Employee")]/@value')
```

Answer (score 1):

You got `SyntaxError` exception because of inconsistent usage of single and double quotes

Just try to mix single/double quotes as below

```
value = tree.xpath("//option/@value[starts-with(.,'Employee')]")
```